# UITableView row count in didSelectRowatIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

how can i get UITableView row count in didSelectRowatIndexPath.can any one tell me a good way to get it

Comment: i cant able to get your question clearly.. can you edit your question more cleary....

Comment: do you want total numbers of rows in did select row method or you want the rowno of the selected row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
    return [array count];----->this is the row count You have to use in didselect row method  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%i", [indexPath row]);
```

and you should get the number of the row selected returned in the console. Alternatively you could pass [indexPath row] into a variable and use it inside a conditional statement to perform a different action depending on row selected like this:

```
int rowSelected = [indexPath row];

if(row == 0)
{
     //do something
}
else if(row == 1)
{
    //do something else
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, first line of code should read NSLog(@"%i, [indexPath row]);

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the number of records passed in **numberOfRowsInSection** for all sections. If its varying you can keep a variable that stores the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=indexPath.row;
```

the a variable has the value you want